# Is this part of a claw to a Dinosaur?

Tags: species-identification, bone, fossil

[image][image][image][image]Agitzed claw 1 large and 1 smaller  underneath.  What I found is about 4" long and about 3/4" in diameter which gets smaller towards the tip. Underneath it appears to be another small claw tip about 11/4" long and appears 1/4" in diameter. They look like stone or aeget.

Comment: There are  many fossil id forums where specialists often know the latin name of 150 types of ammonites and they know a lot about tdino claws too.

Comment: What's the rock matrix - typically fossils are only found in sedimentary rocks...

Comment: Where is this from geographically? What formation?

Comment: I discovered it in the Pacific Northwest on one of the beaches off vashon

Comment: without knowing the rock type or higher quality images it could be coral or crinoid, or a dozen other aquatic animal fossils. dinosaur fossil is very porous so its unlikely.